# How to keep the user logged in after a Refresh in auth0-js?

Tags: reactjs, auth0

Authentication.js:

```
silentAuth() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    this.auth0.checkSession({}, (err, authResult) => {
      console.log("Auth result: " + authResult);
      if (err) return reject(err);
      this.setSession(authResult);
      resolve();
    });
  });
}

setSession(authResult, step) {
  this.idToken = authResult.idToken;
  this.profile = authResult.idTokenPayload;
  // set the time that the id token will expire at
  this.expiresAt = authResult.expiresIn * 1000 + new Date().getTime();
}
```

Inside the App component:

```
async componentDidMount() {
  if (this.props.location.pathname === '/callback') return;
  try {
    await auth0Client.silentAuth();
    this.forceUpdate();
  } catch (err) {
    if (err.error === 'login_required') return;
    console.log("ERROR: " + err.error);
  }
}
```

What I expect is that unless I logged out from the app, checkSession must return a valid authResult but it returns undefined when I refresh the page? So I want the user to keep logged in after Refresh?

Comment: Did you ever figure out the answer to this? I read that auth0 recommends not storing tokens in local-storage so I think you are on the right track.

Answer (score 1):

How about using something like localStorage to store your state?

```
localStorage.setItem("loggedIn", true)
```

....

```
localStorage.getItem("loggedIn")
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `authResult` should contain different fields including:

- `idToken`
- `access_token`
- `expiresAt`
- ...

I would recommmend to store those values in your LocalStorage or SessionStorage on login and retrieve it on application state. I would not recommend to store `loggedIn` with a boolean value since this might has changed according to the `expiresAt` attribute. So an `isAuthenticated` in your `AuthService` that determines the current real state according to the availability of `access_token` and `expiresAt` in the context of the current time would be the appropriate way to go.